# Is the cone of the zero map $A \to B$ always $A[1] \oplus B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a triangulated category, with objects $A, B \in \mathcal{D}$. Is it true that
$$A \xrightarrow{0} B \to A[1] \oplus B \to A[1] \tag{$*$}$$
is a distinguished triangle?

If $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ is the derived category of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, one can just compute the mapping cone of the $0$-map, which turns out to be $A[1] \oplus B$.

The triangle $(*)$ looks like it is the direct sum of the two triangles
$$\begin{array}{c}
A & \to &0 & \to & A[1] & \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}_{A[1]}} & A[1]\\
0 & \to &B & \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}_B}  & B & \to & 0,
\end{array}$$
but none of the axioms of a triangulated category state that direct sums of triangles are triangles. Or am I missing something here?

More generally, I wonder: Why does the definition of a triangulated category involve an additive category, but there is no connection between triangles and biproducts?

Comment: You could define something like a "pre-triangulated" category, which would only be pre-additive and not additive, with the same axioms, but then of course you only get weaker results about them.

Comment: @CaptainLama Afaiu, "pre-triangulated" categories are missing the octahedron axiom, so we have to be careful with that naming ;) Actually, I also read right now in the book of Neeman, that it is sufficient to assume that $\mathcal D$ has a zero object, and that $Hom$ sets are abelian groups, associative wrt composition.Then biproducts follow from the other axioms. He does not explain this in detail though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a pre-triangulated category the direct sum of triangles  is a triangle. A proof of this (and in fact a stronger statement) can be found at [Lemma 13.4.9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QS) of the Stack project.

Your question was also [answered on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4782/splitting-in-triangulated-categories).